# the Hilbert algebra and spectrum

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let‎ ‎$ H = \ell‎^{2}(\mathbb n) $, and let
$‎S : H ‎‎\longrightarrow‎‎ H$‎‎ be the unilateral shift 
$$ S(x‎_{‎1‎}‎, x‎_{‎2‎}‎, \ldots) = (0, x‎_{‎1‎}‎ , x‎_{‎2‎}‎,\ldots) . $$‎‎

> **Show ‎that:**
>
> ‎>$‎S ‎\in ‎B(H)$,
>
> $ ‎‎\| S‎\|= 1 $,
>
> $‎\sigma(S) = \{ ‎\lambda \in ‎\mathbb{C} : ‎\mid\lambda\mid\leqslant 1\}‎‎$‎‎

Answer (score 1):

Show that $S^*S=I $. For the spectrum, show that any $\lambda $ with $|\lambda|<1$ is an eigenvalue of  $S^*$.

Comment: please help me for eigenvalue of  $S^{2}$.

Comment: how can we show that the norm is 1?